# Bing maps pushpins in REST

Tags: rest, bing-maps, pushpin

I am using bing maps REST services and I need to add pushpins but surprisingly it's giving me a hard time. I found out how to easily add pushpins in AJAX services, but that would need me to include scripts and stuff to my pages which I'd really rather skip. I tried searching the internet for information on how to add pushpins in REST ( or simply an iframe with a URL ) but I failed to find any useful such. Does anyone know how I can add pushpins in REST?

**EDIT**: I'm using dynamic maps based on this link http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/viewer.aspx?showCopyright=false&cp=43.835109710693~25.957630157471&lvl=1&w=250&h=350&sty=r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the Bing Maps Imagery REST service, you will be able to add pushpin based on the URL parameters, see the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Here is an sample request that will allow you to add pushpins, take a look at the `pp` parameter:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/47.619048,-122.35384/15?mapSize=500,500&pp=47.620495,-122.34931;21;AA&pp=47.619385,-122.351485;;AB&pp=47.616295,-122.3556;22&key=BingMapsKey

If you are using embedded maps, here is the list of parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692180.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but that is a static map, I seem to have missed to mention that I'm using dynamic maps, like the following, where the parameter `pp` doesn't seem to make a difference :/
http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/viewer.aspx?showCopyright=false&cp=43.835109710693~25.957630157471&lvl=1&w=250&h=350&sty=r

Comment: TThe complete list of the parameters can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692180.aspx

Comment: That seems to do the trick but there are so little parameters, I can barely control anything. I need the easing or 'inertia' effect and I need to be able to change the pushpin icon, there must be some more parameters that aren't really shown here O.O

Comment: No, if you won't to do this, you will need to integrate the Bing Maps AJAX v7 control. Here are some examples: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7